# How can I get all parent keys given a specific child key in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to return an array of parent keys that contain the given child key.

Here is my database (member user IDs with the IDs of every group they are in):

[image: database].

For example:

- If I provide `-Lu3Zs4FCW6F4IcMSU8K` it should return the two parent keys, `SnGXDFilErWEqFxPgWY5bIIAnPA3` and
  `t1S9N9owgKRGqBaNxs02rru8GpD3`.
- If I provide `-Lu3gCYh5QUplnwLdOFA` it should only return `t1S9N9owgKRGqBaNxs02rru8GpD3`

The child values (0 or 1) are not known.

Here is what I tried so far:

```js
var members = [];

return await firebase.database().ref('members').orderByChild(groupId).once('value', snap => {
    snap.forEach(data => {
        members.push(data.key);
    });
}).then(() => {
    return members;
});
```

But this code returns both member keys no matter what child key I provide. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current data structure allows you to efficiently find the groups for a given member. It does however not allow you to efficiently find the members for a given group.

To allow the latter use-case, consider adding an additional data structure that is pretty much the inverse of what you have now:

```
"groups": {
  "-Lu3Zs4FCW6F4IcMSU8K": {
    "SnGXDFilErWEqFxPgWY5bIIAnPA3": true,
    "t1S9N9owgKRGqBaNxs02rru8GpD3": true
  },
  "-Lu3gCYh5QUplnwLdOFA": {
    "t1S9N9owgKRGqBaNxs02rru8GpD3": true
  }
}
```

Now you can look up the members of a group in the same way you look up the groups of a member.

Also see my answer here:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)